# How to filter rows by using datetimes present in the row and datetime('now')

Tags: sqlite

Given the table Use, defined as

```
CREATE TABLE Use(date TEXT NOT NULL, id TEXT PRIMARY KEY);
```

I want to make a query to find "All uses before today", however SQLite is not behaving as I expect and return the wrong value.

I tried to query using my table as such:

```
SELECT * FROM Use WHERE date <= datetime('now')
```

Comment: yes. Marking this as a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `date` might not be in the same format that `datetime` returns.

You need first to convert the `date` to use the same format, by using the `datetime` function on it as well, and then you can compare both correctly:

```
SELECT * FROM Use where datetime(date) <= datetime('now')
```